# How to use a web user control in code only (no rendering)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control which has panels and other gui controls. It's used like any user control in rendering a web page. However I have a need to use a new instance of it and use it in code only without rendering it as it has business logic which I want to use. However it gets object null reference errors during run whenever a gui control is referenced in code, for example: `pnlSomePanel.Visible = true;`

How do I use a user control in code only (without it being rendered)? Using .NET 4.0.

Comment: This sounds like a case of separation of responsibility. I would suggest refactoring your code so that the logic in the panel is separated and callable from both the panel and where you are trying to call it from now.

Comment: The code is not specific to the panel. Code reference gui objects. The uc has methods calling other methods and they all use properties in the uc so uc is pretty to be used as a whole. I don't have resources to refactor this big uc. I just need a bandaid solution to use the uc in code only. Otherwise I have to duplicate the code which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you should just be able to create a new instance of the code-behind class (assuming an asp.net web application and not a web site).

However, if there is business logic embedded in that user control, I would suggest moving it into a separate class or exposing the business logic as a static method with an appropriate set of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

Add a reference to your module on the page.

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/modules/MyModule.ascx" %>
```

Then, you can create an instance of that module in your code behind using the class name of the module.

```
modules_MyModule ctrl = LoadControl("~/modules/MyModule.ascx") as modules_MyModule;
ctrl.SomeMethod();
```

The next step *would* be to add it to a parent container, but if you skip that step, you should still have a functional object in the code behind.  Not totally sure if it will work, but in theory it should.